# hover for 2 seconds fadeIn/out sibling not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I manage to get hovering for 2 seconds to fadeIn/Out on a ID or a Class (which catches all with the same class obviously), but i can't get this working on a (this).sibling("className")

Also the fadeIn/Out or toggleFade works fine without the if statement... I have run out of ideas to get hovering for more than 2 seconds before make a sibling element fadeIn

```js
var timeoutId;
$(".cell-inner").hover(function() {
  if (!timeoutId) {
    timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
      timeoutId = null; // EDIT: added this line
      $(this).siblings(".tool-tip").fadeIn();
    }, 2000);
  }
});

function() {
  if (timeoutId) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = null;
  } else {
    $(this).siblings(".tool-tip").fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
.tool-tip {
  display: none;
}

.tool-tip:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="text" class="cell-inner">
  <span class="tool-tip">The full text from the input field... Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Within a setTimeout, 'this' doesn't refer to your element anymore (but to the window-object). option 1): outside of setTimeout, make a local reference to 'this' , by doing something like 'var self = this' , and then use 'self' inside the 'setTimeout' function. Option 2) , use `setTimeout(() => {...})`. I.e.: arrow-syntax which keeps a reference to 'this' from the outside scope. Beware: Not all browsers support arrow-functions yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your snippet is broken because you've placed an unassigned anonymous function at the end of the block. I presume this is intended to be the second argument to the `hover()` call instead.

The other issue with your logic is because the `setTimeout()` handler function runs under a different scope than the `mouseenter` handler function, hence `this` in your code does not refer to the element which raised the event.

To fix the problem create a variable in the event handler which holds the element reference which you can then use inside the timeout. Note that you can also simplify the `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` calls, like this:

```js
var timeoutId;

$(".cell-inner").hover(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    $el.siblings(".tool-tip").fadeIn();
  }, 2000);
}, function() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  $(this).siblings(".tool-tip").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.tool-tip {
  display: none;
}

.tool-tip:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="text" class="cell-inner">
  <span class="tool-tip">The full text from the input field... Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</span>
</div>
```

You should also note that what you're attempting to do is possible in CSS alone. This approach is better practice than using JS, where possible.

```css
.tool-tip {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
  transition-delay: 2s;
}
.cell-inner:hover + .tool-tip {
  opacity: 1;
}


.tool-tip:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" class="cell-inner">
  <span class="tool-tip">The full text from the input field... Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The anonymous function was the second parameter to .hover() before the edit. I think @DreamTeK might made a mistake.